# Install-ADDSDomain is not recognized

Tags: windows, powershell, module

Install-ADDSDomain is not recognized as cmdlet even I fI tried to import the module ADDSDeployment it says no valid module file was found in any module directory I have Windows Server 2008 R2 with upgraded powershell to v 3.0

Thank you

Comment: You might get more help to your questions, if you vote up answers and mark off answers. Just an FYI for the StackExchange sites. This community is reputation-driven. The least you could do for someone taking the time to help you, is click a "vote up" and "mark as answer" button.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand you there is not mark as answer button  or vote up that I encountred in this site and I don't have any idea about